# LINQ - Find all records where all items in a given list are contained in an icollection

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

I have a list of filters and I want to use it to query a table where the returned items contain ALL of the values not just one.

The table is called Organisation and contains a list of AgeGroups the organisation is targetted to.

```
public class Organisation
{
public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
public string OrgName { get; set; }
public ICollection<OrgAgeGroup> AgeGroupCollection { get; set; }
}
```

The OrgAgeGroup class is below

```
public class OrgAgeGroup
    {
        public int OrgAgeGroupID { get; set; }
        public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
        public int AgeGroupID { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally the selected values from the checkboxes are stored in an int List:

```
List<int> selectedAges
```

I'm using the following code to select all orgs that contain any of the selectedAges:

```
IQueryable<Organisation> orglist = GetAllOrgs();

 orglist = orglist.Where(o => o.AgeGroupCollection.Any(l => selectedAges.Contains(l.AgeGroupID)));
```

but I cant figure out how to get all orgs that contain all the selected ages. Changing Any to All seems to have no effect on the search. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should give you what you want.

```
orglist = orglist.Where(
    o => selectedAges.All(
        s => o.AgeGroupCollection
            .Select(l => l.AgeGroupID)
            .Contains(s)));
```

You want the organizations `o` where all the `selectedAges` `s` are contained in the collection of `o`'s `AgeGroupCollection`'s `AgeGroupId`s.